# SQL Update/Merge - how to get update statements that make source table unnecessary

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2019

I have a table Links with fields code (string) and link (string). Some of the links are NULL, so I need to update those values based a correct full mapping in excel (sheet has the same fields). Now, this should be easy, and it is on my local machine, because I can just import the excel sheet into SQL Server. But, in the production servers, I am not able/allowed to add to the existing tables, only to run queries. I have been requested to get SQL to produce a query that would do the same job as the update/merge I am describing--without adding the source table.

Wondering if there is any setting or command that would allow me to access the end-product updates (containing the string form of code and link) that run when I run the update query on my local machine with the other table. Using SQL Server/SSMS 2019.

| code | link |
| --- | --- |
| PM.23.fd | http://... |
| PM.25.df | NULL |

| code | link |
| --- | --- |
| PM.23.fd | http://... |
| PM.25.df | http://... |

Comment: If you are not able to import excel data on server side then you can import the excel sheet on your local machine and generate the table script with data and run that script  on the server side and update the null values.

Comment: Can you not use SSMS Import/Export Wizard to the production server? Can you not at least import it to a temp table?

Comment: @Charlieface No, security won't allow it (gov stuff). Really would rather not have to make a temp table at all bc I'll have to submit a request but might not be possible.

Comment: Temp table is literally just `create table #tmp (columnshere)` and every user has permissions to do that, as it's stored in `tempdb`. What *do* you have permissions to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "pseudotable" in form of `values('pm.25.df', 'http://xyz'),('other', 'http://abc')` and then ask the guy to do a merge on the pseudo table in form of:

```
-- Create testdata
select *
into #sometable
from 
(
    VALUES  (N'PM.23.fd', cast(N'http://dontchange.com' as nvarchar(255)))
    ,   (N'PM.25.df', NULL)
) t (code,link)


-- the script

;merge #sometable as target
using (
    select * from (
        values  ('pm.25.df', 'http://stackoverflow.com') -- here you generate your changes
        ,   ('pm.xyz', 'http://example.com')
        ,   (N'PM.23.fd', N'http://change.com')
        ) x(code, link)
    ) as source
    ON source.code = target.code
when matched and target.link IS NULL then update set link = source.link
when not matched then insert (code, link) values(source.code, source.link)
;
```

I use merge because you mentioned it, but if you only interested in update, you can just change the query:

```sql
UPDATE  target
SET link = source.link
FROM    #sometable target
INNER JOIN (
        VALUES  ('pm.25.df', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
        ,   ('pm.xyz', 'http://example.com')
        ,   (N'PM.23.fd', N'http://change.com')
    )  source (code, link)
    ON  source.code = target.code
WHERE   target.link IS NULL
```

This only updates codes where link is null.

If you have more than 1000 rows, then values will not work, then you generate a temp table that you insert into